# Python module cx_Oracle ld installation issue on Solaris11U3 SPARC: fatal: file /oracle/database/lib/libclntsh.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64 error

Tags: python, cx-oracle

Trying to install cx_Oracle on Solaris11U3 but getting ld: fatal: file /oracle/database/lib/libclntsh.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64 error

## python setup.py build

running build
running build_ext
building 'cx_Oracle' extension
cc -DNDEBUG -KPIC -DPIC -I/oracle/database/rdbms/demo -I/oracle/database/rdbms/public -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c cx_Oracle.c -o build/temp.solaris-2.11-sun4v.32bit-2.7-11g/cx_Oracle.o -DBUILD_VERSION=5.2.1
"SessionPool.c", line 202: warning: integer overflow detected: op "<<"
cc -G build/temp.solaris-2.11-sun4v.32bit-2.7-11g/cx_Oracle.o -L/oracle/database/lib -L/usr/lib -lclntsh -lpython2.7 -o build/lib.solaris-2.11-sun4v.32bit-2.7-11g/cx_Oracle.so
ld: fatal: file /oracle/database/lib/libclntsh.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 2

Tried all available information on the internet:
Installed gcc
Installed solarisstudio12.4
Installed instantclient-basic-solaris.sparc64-12.2.0.1.0, instantclient-odbc-solaris.sparc64-12.2.0.1.0
Set LD_LIBRARY_PATH to oracle home directory:instantclient_12_2/

Same issue seen while installing DBD:Oracle perl module.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot mix 32-bit and 64-bit together. Everything (Oracle client, Python, cx_Oracle) must be 32-bit or everything must be 64-bit. The error above looks like you are trying to mix a 64-bit Oracle client with a 32-bit Python.